# URL masking in Python Django

Tags: python, django

I have built a website using Django framework(www.example.com). While navigating the site the URL changes to like (www.example.com/home or /profile etc).
Is there some way that the current url is masked by a placeholder eg(www.example.com/home should be shown as www.example.com).
This should work throughout the website.
The url shown to the user would remain same (www.example.com) to where ever the user navigates on the site

Comment: Why on Earth would you want to do that? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page

Answer (score -1):

**HIGHLY NOT RECOMMENDED**

1. Keep a single link in your `urls.py`, containing `r'^$'`.
2. Handle all requests purely as `POST` request.

Note: You'll have to hard code every parameter, and detect manually from where the request is coming.

To know how to work with `POST` request in detail check [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.method)